# Redirect robots to robots-beta.txt when the beta.* prefix is being used

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to disable all indexing on all content coming from my beta.* sub-domain. I don't actually have a beta/ directory on the server. The app is smart enough to switch the user to the beta code when it sees the beta prefix in the url.

Anyway, what I'm trying to do is redirect all robots to robots-beta.txt when the beta.* prefix is being used, but I'm having a hard time getting that to work. I've tried this in my htaccess file and tried modifying my virtual host but nothing seemed to work out.

```
# Disable beta.* indexing
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^beta\.sitename\.com$
RewriteRule ^robots.txt$ http://beta.sitename.com/robots-beta.txt [L]
```

**Edit:**
Or if there's a way to do it in the original robots.txt file, that'd be better I think. Something like?

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: beta.*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have always set my robots.txt like this (I'm using PHP):

```
<?
$pos = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], ".gridserver.com"); // this is my temp domain

if ($pos === false) { ?>
    User-agent: *
    Disallow: /admin/
    Disallow: /ajax/

    Sitemap: http://<?= $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ?>/sitemap.xml
<? } else { ?>
    User-agent: *
    Disallow: /
<? } ?>
```

Then in my .htaccess:

```
<FilesMatch "^robots.txt$">
  SetHandler php-script
</FilesMatch>
```

Though to be honest, I quite like your way!